# Are we close enough to objects?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

Are we able to touch the atomic orbital of an element ?

If so, wouldn't there be a current flowing ?

If not, then where do we actually touch when we hold it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are we able to touch the atomic orbital of an element ?

If we define "touch" as the exchange of virtual photons between our hand and the object, yes. The Pauli exclusion principle, to start with, does not allow the electron orbitals in our hand to overlap with the electron orbitals of the surface unless very specific quantum mechanical conditions are fulfilled.

> If so, wouldn't there be a current flowing ?

since we are sensing something in our sensors, yes , currents are flowing , but not from the orbital per se. It will depend on the type of material, the chemical bonds and the [Van der Waals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) forces between our skin atoms/molecules and the atoms/molecules of the object. Some are sticky, showing strong bonds some are slippery, showing weak ones etc. Depending on the interaction an electron from the higher orbit of the molecular orbitals might transfer to our hand creating a tiny current detectable by our neurons , or pressure differentials are established that transmit a signal, etc, going into biophysics  and biochemistry models which I am not familiar with .

Comment: Nobody has ever touched "matter", only energy

Answer (score 0):

When we touch things we are actually feeling the electromagnetic force of repulsion. There are atoms in our hands and in every object. This force (one of the four fundamental) is responsible for what we feel. This force means that we come nowhere near to the orbits of the atoms in the object, at least in comparison.
What we feel is the repulsion force.